# Error:cannot find symbol class RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hiii"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1 - Copy.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
   }
```

I cannot use RecyclerView and Linearlayoutmanager .i have Tried to Compile the older version  too but every time it comes with error Cannot resolve symbol'recyclerview'.please help me

Comment: you can add design support to use `recyclerview` like, `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add also the v7 recyclerview library. Add this to the dependencies of your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```